# Unable to understand - reading characters from files in C

Tags: c, file-handling

I have just started learning file handling in C, and wondered if I could perform mathematical calculations by reading input from a file, here is the code for just reading the characters and displaying on the console :

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *p;
    char a, b, c, ch;

    p = fopen("numbers.txt", "a+");

    while((ch = getc(p)) != EOF)
    {
        fscanf(p, "%c %c %c\n", &a, &b, &c);
        printf("%c %c %c\n", a, b, c);
    }
    fclose(p);

    return 0;
}
```

numbers.txt contains (with a space before each character) :

```
 2 + 3
 5 + 6
 6 + 7
```

output obtained is :

```
2 + 3
  + 6
  + 7
```

I am unable to understand why first line output is as expected but second and third line have missing character, even though new line is given after each expression in numbers.txt.

Comment: Please check the return value from `fopen`.

Comment: 1) `"a+"` --> `"r"` 2)  `while((ch = getc(p)) != EOF)
    {
        fscanf(p, "%c %c %c\n", &a, &b, &c);` --> `while(fscanf(p, " %c %c %c\n", &a, &b, &c) == 3) {`

Comment: Also check the return value from `fscanf`

Comment: See a [fix here](http://ideone.com/ZqnUta).

Comment: @Ryan yes, I tried removing spaces in the txt file, but the output was not as expected, I am confused as to why fscanf would eat the first character from all other lines except the first.

Comment: @YashKothari see [DEMO](http://ideone.com/DHRt6s)

Comment: Don't assign `getc(...)` to a `char`; it returns `int` for a reason.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I included your comment in a community wiki answer because it’s right, but if you could add it as an answer, that would probably be best =)

Comment: @Ryan I have not searched, but I think this is a common mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An additional character is being scanned at the beginning of each iteration of your `while` loop

```
while((ch = getc(p)) != EOF)
```

Try making the `fscanf()` statement as the condition for your `while` loop and check for its return value.  According to **[cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/)**:

> **On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument
>   list successfully filled**. This count can match the expected number of
>   items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading
>   error, or the reach of the end-of-file.
>
> **If a reading error happens** or the end-of-file is reached while
>   reading, the proper indicator is set (feof or ferror). And, if either
>   happens before any data could be successfully read, **EOF is returned**.

So try changing your while condition to anyone of the following:

```
while (fscanf(p, " %c %c %c", &a, &b, &c) != EOF)
```

or

```
while (fscanf(p, " %c %c %c", &a, &b, &c) == 3)
```

Answer (score 6):

Using whitespace in the `scanf` format specifier, like you do with `\n`, matches *any amount* of whitespace. The `\n` and the leading space on the next line are consumed, causing `getc` to remove the first digit instead of the leading space.

I’d skip `getc` entirely, as @BLUEPIXY suggested:

```
while (fscanf(p, " %c %c %c", &a, &b, &c) == 3) {
    printf("%c %c %c\n", a, b, c);
}
```